# Проблемы при верстки адаптивного сайта

Tags: html, css

В данный момент верстаю сайт с адаптивным дизайном, и у меня возникли проблемы при верстки адаптива.То есть, проблема заключается в следующем, у меня в header есть фоновое изображение, а поверх изображения находится лого и навигация по сайту. Сначало я создал новый класс в HTML (section id="main"), и установил путь к файлу с картинкой через селектор #main, но когда я сужжаю web-страницу, моя картинка не сужжается, а просто обрезается или тупо исчезает, вроде высоту и ширину я задавал, я не знаю как можно это решить, пол дня потерял разбираясь с этим.

Answer (score 0):

Ширину картинки в % пробовали задавать?

`max-width: 100%;
height: auto;`

Comment: это в style.css или в файле с адаптивной версткой?

Кстати, устанавливал для #main width: 100%; min-height: auto; в style.css и в файле с адаптивной версткой, но все равно такая же ерунда))

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Но также, когда устанавливаю height: auto; , изображение просто исчезает

Answer (score 0):

Вот например у вас есть header, для него задан фон, если вы хотите, чтобы изображение масштабировалось при изменении окна то для header задайте сдедующие стили:
`.header{`
`width: 100%;`
`height: auto;`
`background-image: url("путь к вашей картинке");`
`background-repeat: no-repeat;`
`background-size: no-repeat;`
`}`